# Python Pandas: What is the most efficient way to compare two lists in a loop?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, pandas, comparison

I have a ground truth dataset 'gt' (with 100 entries) which looks like this:

```
    org_o                  shh group
    ArabsGate               1   1
    ArabsGate Company       1   1
    AS EMT                 NaN  2
    AS EMT Mobile Internet  1   2
    DigitalEffex (MH)      NaN  3
    DigitalEffex            1   3
    Aruba S.p.A.            1   4
    Aruba S.p.              1   4
```

and I would like to compare it to a huge dataframe 'df' which looks like this:

```
        match           org_o 
        as emt        AS EMT                   
        as emt        AS EMT Mobile Internet    
        digitaleffex  DigitalEffex (MH)    
        digitaleffex  DigitalEffex
        digitaleffex  Digital
```

As a result of comparision I want to if the same group with the same org_o exists in my df or not. So for each group both counts or members of the group, and actual org_o names. So for instance where we have both  'Aruba S.p.A.' and 'Aruba S.p.' in df and wether they are matched to a same keyword ('match' column) in one group.

Here is what I did, but is not really what I am looking for.

```
gt.groupby('group').count()['org_o']
df.merge(gt, on  = 'org_o')
```

Eventually I would like to count false positive/negatives. this is the expected output:

```
        match           org_o                 tag
        as emt        AS EMT                   TP
        as emt        AS EMT Mobile Internet   TP   
        digitaleffex  DigitalEffex (MH)        TP
        digitaleffex  DigitalEffex             TP
        digitaleffex  Digital                  FP
```

Can anybody help with it?

Comment: Could you also post expected output? In other words, you want replace `gt` 's `org_o` names from `df`'s `match` and then take the counts or .. ?

Comment: Are you only comparing the values in the first column? What's wrong with doing a loop over each list? The runtime will be O(n*m) where n and m are the sizes of each list.

Comment: @tommy.carstensen yes and the fact that they belong to the same group in the gt data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like what you need is simple lookup -

```
df['tag'] = np.where(df['org_o'].isin(gt['org_o']), 'TP', 'FP')
```

Here we are adding a new column `tag` to the `df`. We are using numpy's [where](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) function to check if the `org_o` in `df` is present in `gt`. If yes, then assign `TP` as the value of the `tag` to that row, otherwise assign `FP`.

As far as efficiency is concerned, this "lookup" is fairly efficient, because when using `isin`, pandas will convert the values to compare (in this case `gt['org_o']`) [into a set](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/69087192747ea670e1e781b25371f40ffec31073/pandas/core/series.py#L2242), so the lookup time will be O(n * log m)

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do it.

Assign the `tag` column initially with 'FP'

```
In [4]: df['tag'] = 'FP'
```

Filter out rows with `gt['org_o']` values in `df['org_o']` using `df['org_o'].isin(gt['org_o'])`

And, assign the `tag` column with `TP`

```
In [5]: df.loc[df['org_o'].isin(gt['org_o']), 'tag'] = 'TP'

In [6]: df
Out[6]:
          match                   org_o tag
0        as emt                  AS EMT  TP
1        as emt  AS EMT Mobile Internet  TP
2  digitaleffex       DigitalEffex (MH)  TP
3  digitaleffex            DigitalEffex  TP
4  digitaleffex                 Digital  FP
```

I find @Shashank's answer elegant. A minor addition would be in case, if `gt['org_o']` has repetitive values, you can take unique array instead.

```
df['tag'] = np.where(df['org_o'].isin(gt['org_o'].unique()), 'TP', 'FP')
```